# Get data from multiple models of custom module in magento to edit a single form in admin

Tags: magento, models, mage

How to use Mage::register for loading data from 3-4 models while editing a single form of custom module in magento admin?or any other way?

I have a form in magento admin through my custom module , it has 4 tabs and each tab's data is saving to different table,but I am facing problem while fetching the data to display in fields for editing.

Any way to do this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to save 4 models in single Mage::register?

Comment: yes and finally I have done it , but now I am stuck with multiple file uploading in form ....Can u pls help me out???Thanks for your interest

Comment: This is your new question so post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Save each model in an array and then save it in the register.
for example:

```
$array['model1'] = $model_1;
$array['model2'] = $model_2;
```

and then save it as `Mage::register('myModels',$array);`